# Image Hosting for Web Service

Tags: web-hosting, php, images, looking-for-hosting, image-hosting

I'm working on a website that would have a mass of uploaded images, each with a max of 2mb but adding up, in total, to *much* more than my VPS hosting (which has a max of 100gb used up by a lot of other similar projects) allows. I can not pay for a bigger plan and the website itself, as a .org, will likely not have advertising on it.

Everything including the PHP, CSS, JavaScript and website logos and artwork can be stored locally. It's just the images that cannot.

What I'm looking for is something that is free, doesn't track people, is reliable and easy to work with using PHP/JS and HTML. I don't want something that would require all the people using my website to also be logged into the image host.

Cheers,
MyUser

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure of the terms and conditions of imgur's services, but you could look into a hosting provider such as that. Imgur's service limits to 1,250 uploads per day, and if you are providing a free service then hopefully you won't exceed that. If you do, then it's time to look into more robust hosting. Here's a link to their limitations:

> https://api.imgur.com/#authentication

If that will work, users could upload images to your web service, you could use the imgur API (with your API credentials) to store the file, return the URL and link to that for your web service. Here's a link to their API documentation to implement some python on your backend:

> https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython

Comment: Unfortunately Imgur has in it's TOS: "Also, don't use Imgur to host image libraries you link to from elsewhere, content for your website, advertising, avatars, or anything else that turns us into your content delivery network. If you do – and we will be the judge – or if you do anything illegal, in addition to any other legal rights we may have, we will ban you along with the site you're hotlinking from, delete all your images, report you to the authorities if necessary, and prevent you from viewing any images hosted on Imgur.com. We mean it."